# How to detect if VS Code is already installed on Windows Client machine or not

Tags: visual-studio-code, wix, windows-installer

I'm building a WIX Toolset based installer for my app.

To use my app, the user's Windows machine needs to have VS code. I am including `VS code exe` file in my package and I would like to add a conditional statement to decide whether I need to initiate `VS code exe` installation or not.

From the command line, if I type `code --version`, it seems that it returns VS code version information if the PC already has VS code app. I am trying to figure out the way to utilize this information to create a conditional statement...

Appreciate any insights and suggestions!

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically application detection is done using the registry. If you're doing this detection in an MSI you'll want to use [RegLocator](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/registrysearch.html) to set a property. If you're installing using a bundle you'll want to use [RegistrySearch](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/bundle_define_searches.html).

What you'll search for in the registry is going to take some sleuthing for where to search and the values. Just a quick search found this [site](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/37807).